# Insert rows from SQL to array in PHP

Tags: php, sql, database

Can anyone tell me why `row[0]` has data, but `row[1]` to `row[3]` are `undefined` (empty)?

I have 4 rows in my database having `bookid = '35'`.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'assignment3');
$query = "select image from images where BookId='35'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
echo $row[0];
echo $row[1];
echo $row[2];
echo $row[3];
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `fetch_array` every time you want to extend to the next row. Using the numeric indices (`0, 1, 2 ... n`) only retrieve the columns by number in the row.

Try this:

```
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
print_r($row); // row 1
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
print_r($row); // row 2
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
print_r($row); // row 3
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
print_r($row); // row 4
```

If this makes sense to you, you can even abstract this into a `for` loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you have solved my problem! I always mistaken that fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM); fetch each rows from database and insert into each array in php!

Answer (score 0):

It is much convenient to use [`mysqli_fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php), since it returns all the rows as an array in a single step. But it may consume much memory in case of large result-set.

Eg.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'assignment3');
$query = "select image from images where BookId='35'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
//MYSQLI_NUM for numerical array,
//This will return both associative and numerical, if not specify any parameters.
$row = $result->mysqli_fetch_all(MYSQLI_NUM);
//this will print all rows
print_r($row);

//now it is valid to call
echo $row[0];
echo $row[1];
echo $row[2];
echo $row[3];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select image from images where BookId='35'
```

This only returns one column so this is why $row[0] works and $row[1]

You need this:

```
SELECT * FROM images WHERE BookId = '35'
```